# How can I get embed Facebook post code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, embed, koala-gem

I am using [Koala gem](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) to get as a Facebook API client in my Ruby on Rails app.

```
module Clients::FacebookClient

  def self.client(account)
    Koala::Facebook::API.new(account.token, ENV["#{Rails.env.upcase}_FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET"])
  end 
end
```

With this client, I do POST and GET request, But I have not found out the way to I getting the embed code of a particular post.

**Update**:

I try as @CBroe noticed with this post: https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=484231551966124&id=100011378496668, and according with documentation, the GET request was done like this: https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post/oembed.json/?url=https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=484231551966124 but the response is a 404 no found.

Comment: That isn’t implemented via Graph API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/oembed-endpoints

Comment: @CBroe and do you know what about private post? I have regarding user author tokens.

Comment: You can not embed private posts, this feature is only available for public posts.